# SQL join on UID CHAR(20)

Tags: mysql, database, join

I'd like to know if it's ok to join multiple tables on 20 character UIDs, compared to the INT id.

Example UID CHAR(20)

```
zA9z1ieLdblpadjn5Jpd
```

```
select * 
from orderItem oi
    left join order o on o.uid = oi.orderUid
    left join user u on u.uid = o.userUid
    -- several more uid joins
```

I am aware that joining on INTs will always be faster. I am just curious if joining on CHAR UIDs is a bad idea performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

For small tables, INT vs CHAR vs VARCHAR does not matter much.

For huge tables, "random" ids mean "random" fetches which means lots of I/O which means poor performance.

We could discuss further if you provide the pattern used for ids, the pattern for accessing row(s), the size of the table, any secondary keys, the frequency of `SELECTs, and how much RAM you have, etc.

Other tips...  If they are variable length, use `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR`.  If they are always alphanumeric (without accents), use `CHARACTER SET` ascii or latin1, not utf8 or utf8mb4.  I see an upper case "A"; should it match lower case "a"?  Depending on the answer, use the appropriate `COLLATION`.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! What is a small table, how many rows? The UIDs are fixed length of 20, and are generated from this character set: `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. Here's an example of a massive query that joins on IDs at the moment, but I am considering doing the joins on the UIDs: https://pastebin.com/8k1Q4Csb. There are a ton of joins and I am worried it will slow down the app considerably, but I am not sure by how much, since joining on UIDs is much better maintenance wise. Sorry for asking too much. PS: `A` is not equal to `a`.

Comment: @Ivan - When doing `JOINs`, please qualify each column by the table (or alias) it is coming from.  For example, `order by createdDateTime desc` -- what table is that in?  Without knowing, we cannot help you with indexes.@Ivan

Comment: Most of those queries are not hurt much by 20-char keys.

Comment: Again, thank you for the replies. Here's an example of the use case (https://imgur.com/a/7zA9paY). Given the query (https://pastebin.com/8k1Q4Csb) there are a bunch of these joins. I still have IDs, just wont use them. You are saying that this won't be a problem for millions of rows with that query? PS: It's `order by record.createdDateTime desc`